# Проверить по PID наличие файлового дескриптора в /proc

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

Пока не пойму с какой стороны подойти. Есть pid процесса. Мне нужно в /proc/PID/fd проверить есть ли на текущий момент обращение к файлу test.txt и если есть, то сделать kill PID.

Как получить true или false для результата ls -l /proc/PID/fd/ если в результате присутствует (или нет) обращение к файлу test.txt ?

Такой вариант мне кажется не совсем красивым :

```
 ls -l /proc/PID/fd | grep test.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: ну это зависит от того, что вы хотите делать если открыт файл `abctest.txt` или файл `/root/test.txt/not_is_text_file.so`. Или что `test.txt` это действительно регулярный файл, а например не файл устройства или именованный pipe. Каковы границы разумного для проверок что это именно то что вам надо

Comment: Дело в том, что мне не нужно открывать файл. Смысл всей этой карусели в нахождении нужного PID процесса, который использует конкретный файл. И если этот файл есть в /proc/../fd, то по убить процесс по этому PID

Comment: А `lsof` в системе нет ?

Comment: Нет lsof. Если бы был конечно я бы не придумывал

Comment: Вы хотите реализовать: `kill -- $(lsof -t /path/to/test.txt)`?

Comment: Да скорее также работает lsof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

более надёжно будет воспользоваться опцией `-lname` программы *find*:

```
$ find /proc/номер/fd -lname /полный/путь/к/test.txt
```

или, если вам не важен путь, а важно только имя файла:

```
$ find /proc/номер/fd -lname \*/test.txt
```